# How does equilibrium change when pressure is increased?

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium, pressure

What happens to the equilibrium when an **increase in pressure** is applied to a system with the **same number of moles of gas** on both sides of the reaction, according to Le Chatelier's Principle?

For example:

$$
\ce{2 HBr (g) <--> H2 (g) + Br2 (g)}
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Le Chatelier's Principle, when there is an *increase in pressure then the equilibrium will shift towards the side of the reaction which contains fewer moles* of gas and *when there is decrease in pressure, the reaction favors the side with more number of moles*.

In your question, as ***both the side of the reaction contains there same number of moles of gas*** i.e. 2 moles of gas on the left and 2 moles of gas on the right side of the reaction, hence any change in pressure will have no effect on the system.

***Therefore, there is no effect of any change in pressure.***

Answer (score 2):

There will be no change even if the pressure is increased. Because in both sides, the number of molecules are same.And by Le Chateliers principle, the equilibrium should move in the direction of lower pressure, but here, there is no such possibility as the number of molecules on either side is the same ie $\Delta$n = $0$